# find words (AND,OR) in string and make them an array in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Example input:

```
var string = "(Firstname==test1) AND (Lastname==test2) OR (state=Tamilnadu) OR (country=india)"
```

I require output like `{AND,OR,OR}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
/(?!\) )([a-zA-Z]+)(?= \()/g
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT6tA0/2)

```js
var string = "(Firstname==test1) AND (Lastname==test2) OR (state=Tamilnadu) OR (country=india)";
var result = string.match(/(?!\) )([a-zA-Z]+)(?= \()/g);
document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have `mystring.match()` which returns the first match of a given string/regular-expression in `mystring`.
2. You have `mystring.search()` which returns the position of the first occurance of a given string/regular-expression in `mystring` (or -1, if nothing is found).
3. You have `mystring.substr()` which returns a copy of a portion of a string starting from a given position.

With those, you can write a small function which takes 1 string and 1 pattern to match and return an array of all matches.

```
function getMatchesArray(string, pattern)
{
    var outArray = []; // we'll push matches here
    var matchPosition = string.search(pattern);
    while (matchPosition != -1){
        outArray.push(string.match(pattern)[0]); //push the full matched string
        string = string.substr(matchPosition+1); 
        matchPosition = string.search(pattern);
    }
    return outArray;
}
// usage
var string = "(Firstname==test1) AND (Lastname==test2) OR (state=Tamilnadu) OR (country=india)"
console.log(getMatchesArray(string, /AND|OR/)); // [AND, OR, OR]
```

Comment: input : var string = "(Firstname==test1) AND (Lastname==test2) OR (state=Tamilnadu) OR (country=india)"                                                                         i required output is like  if($(#Firstname).val==test1 && $(#Lastname).val==test2 || state $(#state).val==Tamilnadu) { $(#test).hide();}